# Using AWS SES without official PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, guzzle, amazon-ses

I'm exploring AWS Simple Email Service (SES) and I'd like to send emails and maybe check if a domain is verified, but without using official PHP SDK.

Why? Because I think it's too adding too much code into the `vendor` folder for a simple request.

However, it doesn't seem to be simple. Note that I'm using `us-east-1` region.

This is a sample code:

```
$response = Http::withBasicAuth('foo', 'bar')
    ->post('https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com');

$response->throw();
```

This is a snippet from Laravel wrapper around Guzzle, but final implementation is not so important here. I'm talking more about the theoretical side. Of course, the code doesn't work. It actually gives me `200` status code, which seems weird since it should give me either a validation error or authorization error.

I noticed that AWS SES requires some sort of signature plus in the request and also I'm not sure which authentication method it uses.

Does anyone know how to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: this question will probably get flagged and deleted for not being specific enough. anyway, they are just simple rest requests. as long as you give them all the required parameters, the server should respond back with what you need. I'm sure some auth stuff will go in the request header and anything relating to the request will be in the url or body of the request. Their docs will tell you which endpoints you need to send the request to and with what information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought it might not be specific too much and that's why I added some code (which is really what I tried), however, it even doesn't tell me it's wrong auth, incorrect parameters (4xx) validation, etc.

Comment: i would check other header parameters it returns as well as the body. 200 could just mean the endpoint exists

Comment: I believe you need to sign your requests. I've not accessed this API directly before, but typically you send one request to obtain a token and then send that token in an Authorization header along with your subsequent GET requests. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html

Comment: @Typel thanks for this link! I'll check it out tomorrow, but looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the AWS SDK at all if you use the SMTP option that SES offers instead of the default/raw SES option - it is literally just a drop-in replacement for any SMTP server you are already using - should be as simple as just changing your configuration.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp.html

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to use API because I want to fetch if a domain is verified, etc.